# How do I inject JS with CasperJS?

Tags: parsing, casperjs, code-injection

could you tell me please how do I inject js into a page with CasperJS?

I want this after page has been loaded:

- inject `alert(Hello, World!')` or/and
- inject `window.location=stackoverflow.com`
  make screenshot.

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

To switch context from Casper's one to browser simply call casper's `evaluate` method. It enables to evaluate your code in Browser context.

So calling alert should look something like this:

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
  alert('Hello, World!');
})
```

You can read documentation for evaluate method [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)

As this answers both of your questions I would just like you to know that navigating to other web can be more easily done with Casper `open` method as your code will be much easier to read and maintain.